# how use os.scandir to loop all rasters files in the same folder

Tags: python

I'm trying to calcul mean of rasters using this script and add to dataframe.
I was thinking of using `os.scandir` to get all the rasters files in the folder.
The rasters have name such as

- MODIS_2000_01.tif
- MODIS_2000_02.tif
- MODIS_2000_03.tif
- MODIS_2000_04.tif
- MODIS_2000_05.tif

How can one use `os.scandir` to calcul mean for all the rasters and save them in the same dataframe ?

The following code works for one raster in the folder :

```
 row_list = [] 
# I'm guessing that should be out of the loop.
raster_path = "D:/MODIS/" # That's the folder you want to search in for raster files.

with os.scandir(raster_path) as p: # Open the folder containing the rasters as p.
    for raster in p: # Get each raster in the folder.
        if not raster.name.endswith(".tif"): # Only show the files whose name ends with dot tif.
            raster_file = os.path.join(raster_path, raster.name) # Get the full path of the raster, you'll need it in order to open the raster file and access its data. 
            raster = gdal.Open(raster_file) # Open the current raster file.

            # The rest is your code...

            bands = raster.RasterCount

            for band in range(1, bands+1):
                data = raster.GetRasterBand(band).ReadAsArray().astype('float')
                mean = np.mean(data[data != 0]) #calculate mean without value 0
                row_list.append({
                    'raster': os.path.basename(raster_name),
                    'band': band,
                    'mean': mean,
                    'year': 2000,

                })
                print("Band %s: Mean = %s" % (band, round(mean, 2)))

df = pd.DataFrame(row_list)
df.to_csv('band_meanst.csv')
```

Thank you, for your help.

Comment: Does it need to be "os.scandir" or do  you just need to list all the files in the concerned folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not test this code but maybe it can help you or give you an idea about how to approche the problem.

```
raster_path = "D:/MODIS/"
# ...
with os.scandir(raster_path) as p:
    for raster in p:
        if not raster.name.startswith('.') and entry.is_file():
            raster = gdal.Open(raster.name)
            bands = raster.RasterCount
            # ...
```

---

It should look something like this.

```
row_list2000 = [] # I'm guessing that should be out of the loop.
raster_path = "D:/MODIS/" # That's the folder you want to search in for raster files.

with os.scandir(raster_path) as p: # Open the folder containing the rasters as p.
    for raster in p: # Get each raster in the folder.
        if not raster.name.endswith(".tif"): # Only show the files whose name ends with dot tif.
            raster_file = os.path.join(raster_path, raster.name)) # Get the full path of the raster, you'll need it in order to open the raster file and access its data. 
            raster = gdal.Open(raster_file) # Open the current raster file.

            # The rest is your code...

            bands = raster.RasterCount

            for band in range(1, bands+1):
                data = raster.GetRasterBand(band).ReadAsArray().astype('float')
                mean = np.mean(data[data != 0]) #calculate mean without value 0
                row_list2000.append({
                    'raster': os.path.basename(raster_name),
                    'band': band,
                    'mean': mean,
                    'year': 2000,
                    'date': 325,
                })
                print("Band %s: Mean = %s" % (band, round(mean, 2)))
```

---

If you're using a version of Python inferior to 3.6 (like I do).
You need to replace

```
with os.scandir(path) as p:
    for f in p:
        print(f.name)
```

with

```
for p in os.scandir(path):
    print(f.name)
```

Othe wise you'll get an `AttributeError: __exit__` error.

Comment: i rename my question to copy script with ur answers please it like that ?

Comment: raster.name like that  ` raster = gdal.Open(D:/MODIS/MODIS_2000_01.tif)` or like that :  `raster = gdal.Open(D:/MODIS*.tif  ` thank u

Comment: Nah,  raster name found in the for loop. In the for loop you're iterating over all the files in `raster_path` (where raster_path = "D:/MODIS/").

Comment: Nah,  raster name found in the for loop. In the for loop you're iterating over all the files in `raster_path` (where raster_path = "D:/MODIS/"). You don't need the second line in your code (`raster_name = "D:/projetp/Doy_2000/MODIS_2000_01.tif"
`)

Comment: and in this line what it the raster_name `  raster = gdal.Open(raster_name) ` ?

Comment: I added a more complete answer, with comments.

Comment: i use python 3.7 spyder

Comment: that give me dataframe with nothing ?

Comment: You need to debug the thing, print the `raster.name` si if it corresponds with the file that are in the folder containing your .TIF files. Maybe the condition is not appropriate.

Comment: `raster.name
Out[184]: 'MODIS_2000_01.tif'` give me one of raster

Comment: Well does this file exists ? Can you see it using windows explorer ?

Comment: yes the file exists i will edit my question and  rename the script

Comment: Nah, I'm done. You can't keep editing you question. I've answered you question.

Comment: Well that's on you. The deal is, you ask a question and I provide an answer. If the answer helps you, you accepts it. That's it. You can't keep dragging the process. You need to get things done, you can't have me doing your work. Debugging is a big part of programming. If you don't like that you need to quit now. You only comme to SO when you've (honestly) done your part. I've done more than enough, get to work, do your part.